# Selenium Firefox browser is stuck after downloading pdf

Tags: python, selenium

Was hoping someone could help me understand what's going on:

I'm using Selenium with Firefox browser to download a pdf (need Selenium to login to the corresponding website):

```
    le = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@title="Download PDF"]')
    time.sleep(5)
    if le:
        pdf_link = le[0].get_attribute("href")
        browser.get(pdf_link)
```

The code does download the pdf, but after that just stays idle.
This seems to be related to the following browser settings:

```
   fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
   fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
```

If I disable the first, it doesn't hang, but opens pdf instead of downloading it. If I disable the second, a "Save As" pop-up window shows up. Could someone explain how to handle this?

Comment: If you found a solution to this, please share! I have the same issue! Thanks :)

Comment: @jonesy I've managed to make it work with "le[0].click()", but there was a lot of page specific JS stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the best way to solve this was to let Firefox render the PDF in the browser via pdf.js and then send a subsequent fetch via the Python requests library with the selenium cookies attached. More explanation below:

There are several ways to render a PDF via Firefox + Selenium. If you're using the most recent version of Firefox, it'll most likely render the PDF via `pdf.js` so you can view it inline. This isn't ideal because now we can't download the file.

You can [disable pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882416/geckodriver-selenium-auto-download-pdfs/51884002#51884002) via Selenium options but this will likely lead to the issue in this question where the browser gets stuck. This might be because of an unknown MIME-Type but I'm not totally sure. (There's [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488105/868724) that says this is also due to Firefox versions.)

However, we can bypass this by [passing Selenium's cookie session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087985/python-requests-selenium-passing-cookies-while-logging-in) to [requests.session()](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Here's a toy example:

```py
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

pdf_url = "/url/to/some/file.pdf"

# setup driver with options
driver = webdriver.Firefox(..options)

# do whatever you need to do to auth/login/click/etc.

# navigate to the PDF URL in case the PDF link issues a 
# redirect because requests.session() does not persist cookies
driver.get(pdf_url)

# get the URL from Selenium 
current_pdf_url = driver.current_url

# create a requests session
session = requests.session()

# add Selenium's cookies to requests
selenium_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in selenium_cookies:
    session.cookies.set(cookie["name"], cookie["value"])

# Note: If headers are also important, you'll need to use 
# something like seleniumwire to get the headers from Selenium 

# Finally, re-send the request with requests.session
pdf_response = session.get(current_pdf_url)

# access the bytes response from the session
pdf_bytes = pdf_response.content
```

I highly recommend using [seleniumwire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/) over regular selenium because it extends Python Selenium to let you return headers, wait for requests to finish, use proxies, and much more.